# Does WSO2 have billing methods such as Prepaid and Postpaid?

Tags: wso2, billing

i have a project for which i have to monetize my API, and i see that WSO2 can do all that i need. However according to my rechearches, it seems to me that WSO2 has not billing methods such as prepaid or postpaid and i really need to do this.
Do you know any existing alternatives if this is the case?
Cordially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From WSO2-3.0.0 onwards you have the monetization feature which can address your requirement. WSO2 API Manager uses Stripe as its sample implementation billing engine to handle the payments for API monetization. However, you can use any custom implementation with WSO2 API Manager's API Monetization capabilities based on your requirement. Please note that the billing methods are decided by the billing engines and not by the WSO2 products. Refer [link](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/api-monetization/monetizing-an-api/) for more details.

Comment: ok I see clearly now. I refered to 3scale apim which configure the billing method in the App, and for me it should be the same with WSO2. I'll follow the link for further details.
Thank a lot

Comment: Hi Saranki Magenthirarajah, Sorry to bother you, actually I'm having some confusion regarding subscribers logging into the developer portal to subscribe to APIs. Indeed I created a user with the role internal\subscriber and internal\selfsignup and after logging in with this user, I expected that he could only see the APIs created and subscribed to them with the applications to create in the /publisher page, but it seems that this user has the possibility of creating these own applications and I do not see how to withdraw these privileges.